# How to upload a React project to Github so that more people can work on it?

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm new to React I'm wondering what's the process to upload a project to GitHub, which files should I push? and when someone else does the git pull, how should he proceed? which commands should he type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRA will initialize the git when you create a new project... So you just need to add a remote address (the address of your repo on git server, like GitHub....).
After that needs to push changes/commits to Github.

And about git-pull, which's used to fetch files/contents from the git server, when u want to get new changes from the git server, you will use the git-pull command.

Let me write a series of general steps for upload your project on GitHub:

1- create a repository in Github

2- initialize git in your project folder:

```
git init
```

3- add the remote address:

```
git remote add <remote-name> <remote-address>
```

4- add untracked files to stage:

```
git add -A
```

5- Record changes (commit):

```
git commit -m "subject" -m "description (optional)"
```

6- send ur changes to the git server (Github)

```
git push -u <remote-name> --all
```

after that, if you need to get the changes from GitHub (PULL), you just need to use git-pull:

```
git pull <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

NOTE: This explanation was very general, be sure to research about GIT after reading this, there are good courses on YouTube about git...

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to create a repo on GitHub and then push your codes.
using these commends.

```
git add .

git commit -m "subject"
```

git push origin and **your branch**: for example `git push origin master`.
and then the other can clone you're code and work on it.